# Scaling custom draw code for different iOS resolutions

Tags: iphone, xcode, resolution

I am struggling to get my custom drawing code to render at the proper scale for all iOS devices, i.e., older iPhones, those with retina displays and the iPad.

I have a subclass of `UIView` that has a custom class that displays a vector graphic.  It has a `scale` property that I can set.  I do the scaling in `initWithCoder` when the `UIView` loads and I first instantiate the vector graphic.  This `UIView` is shown when the user taps a button on the home screen.

At first I tried this:

```
screenScaleFactor = 1.0;
if ([UIScreen instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    screenScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}
// and then I multiply stuff by screenScale
```

... which worked for going between normal iPhones and retina iPhones, but chokes on the iPad.  As I said, you can get to the `UIView` at issue by tapping a button on the home screen.  When run on the iPad, if you display the `UIView` when at 1X, it works, but at 2X I get a vector graphic that twice as big as it should be.

So I tried this instead:

UPDATE: This block is the one that's right. (with the corrected spelling, of course!)

```
screenScaleFactor = 1.0;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(contentScaleFactor)]) { //EDIT: corrected misspellng.
    screenScaleFactor = (float)self.contentScaleFactor;
}
// again multiplying stuff by screenScale
```

Which works at both 1X and 2X on the iPad and on the older iPhones, but on a retina display, the vector graphic is half the size it should be.

In the first case, I query the `UIScreen` for its `scale` property and in the second case, I'm asking the parent `view` of the vector graphic for its `contentsScaleFactor`.  Neither of these seem to get me where I want for all cases.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Here's the method in my subclassed `UIView` (it's called a GaugeView):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGAffineTransform t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context);
    t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0);

    [needle updateBox];
    [needle draw: context];
}
```

`needle` is of class `VectorSprite` which is a subclass of `Sprite` which is subclassed from `NSObject`.  These are from a programming book I'm working through.  `needle` has the scale property that I set.

`updateBox` comes from `Sprite` and looks like this:

```
- (void) updateBox {
    CGFloat w = width*scale;
    CGFloat h = height*scale;
    CGFloat w2 = w*0.5;
    CGFloat h2 = h*0.5;
    CGPoint origin = box.origin;
    CGSize bsize = box.size;
    CGFloat left = -kScreenHeight*0.5;
    CGFloat right = -left;
    CGFloat top = kScreenWidth*0.5;
    CGFloat bottom = -top;
    offScreen = NO;
    if (wrap) {
        if ((x+w2) < left) x = right + w2;
        else if ((x-w2) > right) x = left - w2;
        else if ((y+h2) < bottom) y = top + h2;
        else if ((y-h2) > top) y = bottom - h2; 
    }
    else {
        offScreen = 
        ((x+w2) < left) ||
        ((x-w2) > right) ||
        ((y+h2) < bottom) ||
        ((y-h2) > top);
    }
    origin.x = x-w2*scale;
    origin.y = y-h2*scale;
    bsize.width = w;
    bsize.height = h;
    box.origin = origin;
    box.size = bsize;
}
```

`Sprite` also has the `draw` and `drawBody` methods which are:

```
- (void) draw: (CGContextRef) context {

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Position the sprite 
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t,x,y);
    t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t,rotation);
    t = CGAffineTransformScale(t,scale,scale);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, t);

    // draw sprite body
    [self drawBody: context];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void) drawBody: (CGContextRef) context {
    // Draw your sprite here, centered
    // on (x,y)

    // As an example, we draw a filled white circle

    if (alpha < 0.05) return;

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, r,g,b,alpha);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(-width/2,-height/2,width,height));
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How, exactly, are you rendering the graphic?

This should be handled automatically in `drawRect:` (the context you get should be already 2x). This should also be handled automatically with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0);` if available (if you need to fall back to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(), assume a scale of 1). You shouldn't need to worry about it unless you're drawing the bitmap yourself somehow.

You could try something like `self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`, with appropriate checks first (this might mean if you display it in an iPad at 2x, you'll get high-res graphics).

Fundamentally, there's not much difference between an iPad in 2x mode and a "retina display", except that the iPad can switch between 1x and 2x.

Finally, there's a typo: @selector(contentsScaleFactor) has an extra s.

Comment: So after adding all the code above, I also corrected the misspelling of `contentScaleFactor`.  That version seems to work now with all hardware!  I think that because I misspelled it in the `respondsToSelector:@selector()` method, it simply didn't respond to that selector, as it isn't a selector.  But Xcode doesn't tell you that a selector doesn't exist, just that the messaged object doesn't respond to it.  Sneaky.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: GCC *can* tell you that a selector has not been defined before use, but you have to enable the warning with `-Wundeclared-selector`. Search for it in the build settings. If there's a corresponding tickybox, use that, otherwise add it to "additional warning flags" or whatever it's called.